# Azure Searching On File Attachments same as Oracle table using a file link in a column

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to get some Oracle databases to work in MSSQL AZURE.

We seem to have most things working except the ability to search on file attachments - eg word,PDF etc.

Oracle lets us index a column in a table that uses a filepath link.

In MSSQL a column in a table can be added using:

[filepointer] VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM
and then an index can be setup so files can then be searched.

I'm trying to use the same oracle table with this extra column to do the search in AZURE

EG - select * from [TESTATTACHSRCH]  where contains ([filepointer],'Text in File')

I managed to get this working in MSSQL with the Oracle table we had used with this extra special column.

I know at this point FILESTREAM is not supported on AZURE & dropping FILESTREAM is not an option due to the size of the files we are searching on which would add too much size to the database.

I am hoping if there was a way i could still achieve this on AZURE, even if existing AZURE cannot do this on its own & there was 3rd party software to do something similar.

Hopefully somebody has hit the same roadblock & could provide some advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The alternative would be moving the attachments to blobs and store them on Azure Storage. Then, you can setup an Azure Cognitive Search which can extract and index content from pdf,word, ppt, etc.

Just using SQL Server / Azure SQL Database I don't think it will work. You can find more information about what I've described in the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-create-indexers?tabs=indexer-portal